# how to create form for multple image upload in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have created form for multiple image upload.but not working that form.only one image uploading..i want multiple images are to be upload to folder and save image name in database..

My View File

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Upload</title>
<style>
#container
{
    width:750px;
    margin:0 auto;
    //border:5px solid #000000;
}
#container form input[type="text"] {
    height:30px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" align="center">
<form name="product" action="<?php echo base_url;?>admin/login/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
<table>
<h3>Add New Product</h3>
<tr><td>Categories</td><td><select name="catid"><option>Categories</option>
<?php if(isset($category_details))
{foreach($category_details as $keys=>$values){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $values['cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $values['cat_name'];?></option>
<?php }
}?>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Product Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="pname"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="file" multiple="true" name="userfile" size="20" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><br>Product Image:</td><td><br><input type="file" name="pimage[]" id="pimage" multiple></td></tr>
    <tr><td><br>Description:</td><td><br><textarea name="pdescription"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td><br>Price:</td><td><br><input type="text" name="price"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD" class="btn btn-primary"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller File

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */

    public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->load->model('admin/category_model');
       $this->load->model('admin/loginauth_model');
       $this->load->model('login_model');
       $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
       $this->load->library('image_CRUD');
     }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('admin/login');

    }
    public function loadproduct()
    {
        $category_details=$this->category_model->getCategoryDetails();
        $outputdata["category_details"]=$category_details;
        $this->load->view('admin/product',$outputdata); 
   }

 public function loginAuth()
 {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Enter Email','required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Enter your Password','required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('admin/login');
            }
           else
            {
                $username=$_POST['email'];  
            $password=$_POST['password'];

               $user_details=$this->loginauth_model->logincheck($username,$password);
               //print_r($checkauth);
               if($user_details)
                 {
                    if($this->session->userdata('adminusername'))
                    {
                        $adminusername=$this->session->userdata('adminusername');
                        $outputdata['username']=$adminusername;
                    }
                       $category_details=$this->category_model->getCategoryDetails();

                        $outputdata['category_details']=$category_details;
                    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$outputdata);
            }
           }
         }

    public function category()
    {
        //$this->load->view('admin/category');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name','category name','required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_desc','category description','required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('admin/category');
            }
           else
            {
               $addcategory=$this->category_model->addcategory($_POST);
               if($addcategory)
             {

               //**************************pending
             $category_details=$this->category_model->getCategoryDetails();

               $outputdata['category_details']=$category_details;
              //print_r($outputdata);
            $this->load->view('admin/categorylist',$outputdata);
             }
        }
    }
    public function categorylist()
    {
                    //echo image_url;
       $category_details=$this->category_model->getCategoryDetails();

        $outputdata['category_details']=$category_details;
        $outputdata['image_url']=image_url;

        $this->load->view('admin/categorylist',$outputdata);
        $this->load->view('admin/category');

 }
public function userdetails()
    {
        $user_details=$this->login_model->userdetails();

        $outputdata['user_details']=$user_details;

        $this->load->view('admin/userdetails',$outputdata);     

    }
 public function upload()
        {
            $productname=$_POST["pname"];
        $description=$_POST["pdescription"];
            $price=$_POST["price"];
            $catid=$_POST["catid"];
        $name_array = array();
     echo $count = count($_FILES['pimage']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
        $_FILES['pimage']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['pimage']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['pimage']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['pimage']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];   
            $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'img/product_uploads/original/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|GIF|PNG|JPG|JPEG';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '150';
            $config['max_height']  = '180';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
                //$products=$this->category_model->addproduct($catid,$productname,$description,$imagename,$imagesize,$price,$path);
            }
            $names= implode(',', $name_array);
/*          $this->load->database();
            $db_data = array('id'=> NULL,
                             'name'=> $names);
        $this->db->insert('testtable',$db_data);
*/          print_r($names);
            //echo FCPATH;
            //$productname=$_POST["pname"];
        //  $description=$_POST["pdescription"];
        //  $price=$_POST["price"];
            //$catid=$_POST["catid"];

        //   $path = FCPATH.'img/product_uploads/original/';                        
        //  $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP","PNG");  
        //  if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  
        //  $imagename = $_FILES['pimage']['name'];  
    //      $imagesize = $_FILES['pimage']['size'];  

        //  list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $imagename);  
            //$products=$this->category_model->addproduct($catid,$productname,$description,$imagename,$imagesize,$price,$path);
              //print_r($products);
    //      $tmp = $_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'];  
//if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$imagename)) {  
        //  $product_details=$this->category_model->getProductDetails();
            //print_r($product_details);
            //if(isset($products)){
                //echo "aa";
        //    $this->loadproduct();
             //}
        //  }  
            //else  
        //  {
            //echo "Image Upload Failed.";  
    //}
    }
public function logout()
    {
        $newdata = array(
        'adminuser_id'   =>'',
        'adminusername'  =>'',
        'adminemail'     => '',
        'logged_in' => FALSE,
        );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

}





/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.codinglikeasir.com/upload-multiple-files-with-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a `multiple` attrinbute to `<input type="file" />`, that's  not going to work.

You'll have to use a third-party module/plugin, like [Uploadify](http://grafikkaos.co.uk/blog/article/108-integrating-uploadify-v3-and-codeigniter), to get this functionality running.

You could also check [this tutorial](http://grafikkaos.co.uk/blog/article/108-integrating-uploadify-v3-and-codeigniter) on how to integrate Uploadify in CodeIgniter (although I can't see anything CodeIgniterish in your code, but you still tagged the question as CI relevant)

Answer (score 0):

a) Instead of writing this `<input type="file" multiple="true" name="userfile" size="20" />` write `<input type="file" name="userfile[]" size="20" />`

b) Inside your controller you can do something like this:

```
$files = $_FILES;
$count = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{

    $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this to open your upload form :

```
echo form_open_multipart('admin/do_upload');
```

After put one or more :

```
<input type="file" name="name" size="20" />
```

And use a function like that :

```
public function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('admin/images', $error);
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about multiple file upload?